# Как разделить урлы одного модуля на несколько разных и раздельно подключить их в global urls.py

Tags: python, django

В общем, у меня в одной аппке есть 2 вида урлов, один для юзера, другой для любого пользователя.
Урлы для юзера хранятся в `user_urlpatterns`, а обычные в `urlpatterns`. В сеттингах их нужно разделить таким образом:

`user_urlpattterns` в `api/me/`

а `urlpatterns` в `api/`

Я пытался указать прямой путь до списка урлпаттернов в глобальных урлах, но джанго хочет именно путь до модуля с урлпаттернами

https://dpaste.org/FHOo

Answer (score 4):

Я решил проблему импортировав из файла модуля урлпаттерны обычные и юзера и подключив их через include, но решение мне нравится не очень, поэтому принимать свой ответ не буду

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from trading.offers.urls import user_urlpatterns as user_offers_urls
from trading.offers.urls import urlpatterns as common_offers_urls


user_urlpatterns = [
    path("offers/", include(user_offers_urls)),
    path("inventory/", include("trading.inventories.urls")),
    path("watchlists/", include("trading.watchlists.urls")),
    path("trades/", include("trading.trades.urls")),
    path("account/", include("trading.accounts.urls")),
]

apipatterns = [
    path("offers/", include(common_offers_urls)),
    path("items/", include("trading.items.urls")),
    path("me/", include(user_urlpatterns)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path(settings.ADMIN_URL, admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(apipatterns)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: а что смущает в собственном ответе?

Comment: @Дмитрий То, что я джун, а таких решений ещё не видел, поэтому сомневаюсь в верности решения

Comment: Если это работает, проходит тесты и в вас не лупит ваш начальник, значит все норм. Очень хорошо, что вы выложили свой вариант, возможно, его подправят и улучшат